# Pool of extended OVERLAPPED objects in a multithreaded environment: where and how to use locking efficiently

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, atomic, iocp

In C++, I've a `Stream` object which abstracts an `HANDLE` on Windows, and I've also various derivatives objects, such as `File`, `TcpSocket`, `UdpSocket`, `Pipe` which derives directly from that `Stream` object, and then I've also a `RequestIo` object which is my own version of the extended `OVERLAPPED` object, that is, the `RequestIo` directly inherits from the `OVERLAPPED` structure.
From now, saying `RequesIo` is the same as saying `OVERLAPPED`.

In the `RequestIo` object I store several useful things that couldn't be stored in a single `OVERLAPPED` structure, such as flags, user pointers and so on.
There I also store a pointer to the next `RequestIo` object, in order to have an intrusive linked list of these objects.

Then, the `Stream` object has 2 heads of this intrusive linked list, one for `RequestIo` objects for reading, and another one for writing. In this way the `Stream` object can have a little pool of these `RequestIo` objects, and don't have to allocate/deallocate them at every i/o operation, nor needs locking because the 2 intrusive list are separated for readings a writings which are the 2 kind of operations that may occur in 2 different threads simultaneously in IOCPs.

When I'll have stream-like objects (such as sockets, or pipes) I will have only 1 `RequestIo` for reading (more than one are just not needed) and one for writing, so I basically do not need locking because at the first `socket.read()` a new `RequestIo` is allocated, inserted in the linked list, and it will be reused over and over again, until the socket is closed and destroyed, the same for writings.

But, there are not stream-like objects (such as random access file, udp sockets) which can issue more than one `RequestIo` for both reading or writing. Let's just consider an UDP socket that can issue N pending `RequestIo` objects for reading datagrams, or a random access file that can issue several `RequestIo` packets for reading/writing to/from different parts of the file.

Here things get complicated. If I have that linked list of `RequestIo` objects, I actually have to traverse that list and see which `RequestIo` is *NOT* pending and issue a new i/o operation with that one.

Said that like this seems easy, but its not:
despite I can set a flag to a `RequestIo` which says "its pending", the problem is not solved: shouldn't that flag be an atomic integer? Since that flag will be unset by some other thread. And what about retrieving the first `RequestIo` available from the linked list, when there are multiple `RequestIo` instanced? Shouldn't also that be an interlocked operation? And insertion on that linked list? E.g. when I allocate a new `RequestIo` packet because all others are pending.

A possible solution I was thinking is to traverse this linked list and check an atomic integer in the `RequestIo` object with CAS (CompareAndSwap) instruction, if 0 it means its not pending, and immediately set it to 1, so another thread will see that one as pending and will go to the next `RequestIo` object. If it can't find any `RequestIo` object it allocates a new one, but here it should lock the linked list head...to insert the new allocated `RequestIo` object!

So, what is basically the fastest and the most effective way to correctly manage a pool of N `OVERLAPPED` (or `RequestIo` in my case) objects, without incurring in massive locking which would degrade performance and the purpose of multithreaded IOCPs?

Comment: I don't understand why you have pending RequestIo instances in the list at all?  You have issued them to the IOCP subsystem with WSABlah calls. You will get them back when the I/O operation is completed, (or failed:), so why are you keeping them in the list as well?

Comment: Also, even for stream services, I usually try to keep at least two receive requests pending, so that the IOCP system does not often get into a situation where no user buffers are available for incoming data.  As for writing, multiple I/O requests are common since, if a buffer is available for writing, you may as well send it now rather than waiting for a complete buffer-array representing, say an HTTP package of an HTML file/page, to be assembled in its entirety befor sending the first chunk.

Comment: I have them in a linked list so I don't have to destroy and reallocate them every time, and I can reuse them even when I close a socket and reopening it. I allocate them once, and reuse them. Basically the object `Stream` has_a N `RequestIo` objects, in a little linked list pool. In this way when you have to do some i/o, you take a `RequestIo` from that linked list and use it for your i/o operation. Otherwise, what do you do *after* the i/o operation is completed with that `RequestIo` ? In the case of reading you can issue a new reading with the same object, but in the case of writing?

Comment: @Marco: Like Harry says, you have two pools: one of free objects, and one of objects in use.  You can move objects between these pools without involving the system allocator.

Comment: Yeah, thanks Ben, but having these 2 separated pools also would involve using locks, I mean: `lock(); get_first_available_RequestIo_for_writing(); remove_it_from_available_list(); unlock();` Because in the same time you try to leave a `RequestIo` packet from the available list, some other thread could finish its i/o operation and put another `RequestIo` in the available list.

Comment: @MarcoPagliaricci you are worrying too much about locks.  A Critical Sectiion should do fine, since is has a primary spinlock and the contention window is very small - you are only pushing/popping a pointer.

Comment: Also, again, I cannot understand why you insist on keeping track of those instances that are in use.  Like Harry suggests below, just shove the used instances back onto the free pool in the completion-handler thread when you are finished with any data buffers contained within.  Same with sockets, same with data buffer instances.

Comment: @Martin: you don't even need a critical section.  InterlockedPushEntrySList and InterlockedPopEntrySList are atomic and multiprocesor-safe.

Comment: Martin, you might want a list of active objects if you want to ensure orderly shutdown by aborting all operations on active objects, or whatever. This is less likely for buffers than sockets/handles; though having an 'active list' for buffers can be a useful debugging aid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep a linked list containing only the unused `RequestIo` objects.  You can pop an object from the head of the list whenever you need one, and push each object back onto the list when you are finished with it.

The [InitializeSListHead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683482%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [InterlockedPushEntrySList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684020%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and [InterlockedPopEntrySList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683648%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions provide an efficient multiprocessor-safe linked list implementation.

Comment: I already thought to this, but also here, I'd need a lock mechanism for these lists. I mean: `lock(); get_first_available_RequestIo_for_writing(); remove_it_from_available_list(); unlock();` and so on

Comment: Yes, you need a lock, but who cares?  It's going to be a Critical Section and the chances of actual contention, (and so requiring a kernel lock instead of the CS spinlock), is minimal.  All you are doing is pushing/popping one pointer to a RequstIo instance - it doesn't take long to do that!

Comment: If the pool of requestIo objects runs out, you need a strategy for handling. Either create another requestIO, so increasing the size of the pool, or arrange thje pool as a blocking queue so that the requesting thread has to wait for instanbces to be released.

Comment: You don't need a lock.  The interlocked push/pop functions are atomic and multiprocessor-safe, i.e., they handle the locking for you.

Comment: Harry: oh, yeah with those APIs you provided basically I'll use a lock-free linked list. Thanks.